# как пробросить запросы с nginx на docker container?

Tags: nginx

стоит nginx на выделенном сервере который принимает запросы.

контейнеры запускаются по ssh и все работает.

нужно как то запросы из внешнего nginx, то есть в браузере ввел к примеру example.com/api, направлять на докер контейнер, где запущен свой сервер и БД

Answer (score 0):

На входном Nginx настройте [проксирование запросов](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/).